# How to detect the song on Spotify without enable device broadcast?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, metadata, spotify

We can detect the current track info when Device Broadcast is enabled in Spotify.I would like to know whether it is possible to get track info without enable device broadcast in android ?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Notification Access** to get the track details